# KQL Query for creation of dashboard azure

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring

i would like to create for dashboard for where I can seen the monitoring health check, everything going fine APIs and their dependence service running the application fine , for 30 minute and 1 hour 4 hours and extra ,
so that can give us to showing what is going our application health check

Answer (score 1):

> where I can see the monitoring health check, everything going fine APIs and their dependence service running the application

You can use the Application Insights logging to know the API and Application related information. you can view the all the data in a single place.

In your **Application Insights -> Monitoring (Logs)** you can see the results
[image]

You can add your KQL query result in a **Dashboard**.
[image]

Refer [Configuring Monitoring and API in Azure API management](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/configuring-monitoring-api-analytics-azure-management-jitul-gogoi) & [Track Issues with Resource Health and Log Analytics](https://cloudadministrator.net/2021/01/13/tracking-issues-with-resource-health-and-log-analytics/) for additional information to add the API health information in Application Insights. After you can add that into Dashboard.